# Using functional programming with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, functional-programming

I'm not really used to use functionals and I cannot get ggplot to work with them.

For some reason this works:

```
function_factory <- function(x){
  times <- function(y) x * y
} 

simple_application <- function(z1, z2){
  times_z1 <- function_factory(z1)
  times_z2 <- function_factory(z2)
  times_z1(3) * times_z2(3)
}

simple_application(3, 3)
```

But this does not:

```
plot_times <- function(z1, z2){
  times_z1 <- function_factory(z1)
  times_z2 <- function_factory(z2)
  library(ggplot2)
  ggplot(data = data.frame(x = 0), mapping = aes(x = x)) + 
    stat_function(fun = "times_z1", xlim = c(1, 1000)) +
    stat_function(fun = "times_z2", xlim = c(1, 1000))
}


plot_times(3, 4)
```

I just get the following error:

```
> plot_times(3, 4)
Warning messages:
1: Computation failed in `stat_function()`:
object 'z1' not found 
2: Computation failed in `stat_function()`:
object 'z2' not found
```

I have a few more complications, but I'm hoping that if I can solve this I could also solve my own problem.
´
I'm pretty sure this has something to do with environments, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Note that with out the function factory this works well:

```
times_three <- function(x) 3 * x
times_four <- function(x) 4 * x
ggplot(data = data.frame(x = 0), mapping = aes(x = x)) + 
  stat_function(fun = "times_three", xlim = c(1, 1000)) +
  stat_function(fun = "times_four", xlim = c(1, 1000))
```

Comment: In the last chunk of code, `times_three` and `times_four` are functions. In the plot_times function, there are objects. I suspect that stat_function requires a function to be passed to the `fun` parameter.

Comment: Simpler than expected: just get rid of the quotes. `fun = times_z1` works.

Comment: Thank you ira and Rui Barradas. Wow, it really worked to remove the quotes. This has been troubling me for hours.

Comment: I still don't don't get why though. I can use times_z1 as a function as I showed in the first chunk of code.

Comment: It has to do with some evaluation thing. I cannot answer since I really don't know much about that subject matter.

Comment: The documentation in `help("stat_function")` is very clear regarding what needs to be passed to the `fun` argument. It doesn't say that you can pass a character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To `stat_function` send not the `"function"`, but the result of get `get("function")`. Example, instead of `stat_function(fun = "times_z1", xlim = c(1, 1000))` do `stat_function(fun = get("times_z1"), xlim = c(1, 1000))`.

```
plot_times <- function(z1, z2){
  library(ggplot2)
  times_z1 <- function_factory(z1)
  times_z2 <- function_factory(z2)
  ggplot(data = data.frame(x = 0), mapping = aes(x = x)) + 
    stat_function(fun = get("times_z1"), xlim = c(1, 1000)) +
    stat_function(fun = get("times_z2"), xlim = c(1, 1000))
}
```

Result:

```
plot_times(3, 4)
```

[image]